# The inverse function theorem

Tags: real-analysis

In the inverse function theorem, we require that $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^{n}  $. Can inverse function theorem apply to $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^{m}$, where $m\neq n$?

Comment: No. But look up the implicit function theorem. It is an extension of the inverse function theorem for functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ with $n > m$.

Answer (score 3):

As James said, no. The theorem requires $m=n$. And we should never expect a map between spaces of different dimensions to be invertible.

That said, there is the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) and the more general [constant rank theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Constant_rank_theorem). Leaving technical details aside, the latter theorem says:

> If $f$ is smooth and the rank of $Df$ is equal to $k$ in a neighborhood of point $x_0$, then $f$ is locally the composition of:
>
> 1. Orthogonal projection from an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a $k$-dimensional subspace.
> 2. Diffeomorphism between open sets in $k$-dimensional spaces.
> 3. Linear injection of a $k$-dimensional space into $\mathbb{R}^m$.
> 4. Diffeomorphism of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

The inverse function theorem is the case $m=n=k$. The implicit function theorem is the case $m>n=k$.

Comment: Won't "linear" in item 3 imply that the range of $f$ is locally in a $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb R^m$?